# New Template Like DisplayTemplate or EditorTemplate in asp.Net Mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

in asp.net Mvc 3 exist two TemplateFolder EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplate that in Code
Use this syntax for access to template

```
 <%= Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)%>
 <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)%>
```

i want create Other Template, ex RowTemplate Folder and Use this Syntax

```
<%= Html.RowFor(m => m.FirstName)%>
```

how can i do this
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom html helper. See these links :

1. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18255/ASPNET-MVC-Creating-Custom-HTML-Helper-Methods.htm
2. http://develoq.net/2011/how-to-create-custom-html-helpers-for-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor-view-engine/
3. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: thanks for answer, but i want use DisplayTemplate pattern for use UiHint and  <%= Html.DisplayFor(m => m.FirstName)%>